# Using Asynctask and listview with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I use AsyncTask to query an SQLite database - contacts.

When I run that code on the android emulator it works fine (probably because I have less contacts added there), but when I run it on my mobile (which it has approx 500 contacts) the app runs slow.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

The Code is below.

```
      private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            ArrayList<Contact> contactsx = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.blacklist);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                // closing progress dialog

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                ArrayList<Contact> contactItemsTemp = new ArrayList<Contact>();

                adapter = new EfficientAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactItems);

                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
                String name = "";
                String id = "";
                String phoneNumber = "";
                // Cursor cursor = null;

                List<Integer> mycontactID;
                mycontactID = db.getAllIDs();

                Iterator value = mycontactID.iterator();

                while (value.hasNext()) {
                    int mg=(Integer)value.next();

                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            null, null, null);
                //  Log.d("edw",Integer.toString(mg));
                    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

                        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                            id = cur.getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            if (id.equals((mg)))
                                ;
                            {
                                name = cur
                                        .getString(cur
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                if (Integer
                                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                                    Cursor pCur = cr
                                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                                    null,
                                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                            + " = ?",
                                                    new String[] { id }, null);
                                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                                        Log.d("number",
                                                pCur.getString(pCur
                                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                                        // Do something with phones
                                        phoneNumber = pCur
                                                .getString(pCur
                                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                    }
                                    contactItemsTemp.add(new Contact(Integer
                                            .parseInt(id), name, phoneNumber));
                                    pCur.close();

                                    Log.d("Name", name);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        cur.close();
                    }

                }
                // na kanw to temp contactItems

                List<Integer> messagesx;
                messagesx = db.getAllIDs();
                String namex = "";
                String phonex = "";
                for (Integer mg : messagesx) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < contactItemsTemp.size(); i++) {
                        if (contactItemsTemp.get(i).getID() == mg) {
                            namex = contactItemsTemp.get(i).getContactName();
                            phonex = contactItemsTemp.get(i).getPhoneNumber();
                        }
                    }

                    contactsx.add(new Contact(mg, namex, phonex));
                }

                adapter = new EfficientAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactsx);


                db.close();


                return null;
            }
        }



public static class EfficientAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>
            implements Filterable {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        // private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<Contact> values;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> values) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            super(context, R.layout.myobject, values);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         * 
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView1(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.myobject, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.contact = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.contact);
                holder.ph_num = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ph_num);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // prepare the alert box
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = null;
                    alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    // set the message to display
                    alertbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove the contact from the blacklist?");
                    // add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click
                    // listener
                    alertbox.setNeutralButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(context,
                                            "Ok button pressed " + pos,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                                            context);
                                    db.deleteContact(values.get(position)
                                            .getID());
                                    db.close();
                                }
                            });

                    alertbox.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(context,
                                            "Cancel button pressed " + pos,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                    alertbox.show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + pos,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    // .show();
                }
            });

            holder.contact.setText(getItem(position).getContactName());
            holder.ph_num.setText(getItem(position).getPhoneNumber());

            return convertView;

        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView contact;
            TextView ph_num;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Contact getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return values.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void add(Contact con) {
            values.add(con);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void replace(int index, Contact con) {
            values.set(index, con);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void clear() {
            values.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void remove(Contact con) {
            values.remove(con);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure about the exception, but it seems like you are trying to add contacts to your contactx arraylist before you initialize it. You declare it as an instance variable, but do not initialize it until the very end of your doInBackground() method.  That would throw null pointer...

try putting the line..

```
contactx = new ArrayList<Contact>();
```

In your onPreExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.blacklist);
```

I would take a look at this line. You're trying to find your list view from a nested class. Although this will be run on the UI thread, AsyncTask is still not an activity. I beleive your null point is becuase your listview reference is null as an instance of AsyncTask cannot retreive views.

Comment: This is true.. I don't know why you are even able to compile this code, an asynctask is not a view.. so I am pretty sure it does not have a findViewById method.. unless this task is nested inside of an activity..

Comment: @Joel It is inside of an activity. But I do not think you can reference it in that manner anyway. The code compiles but the ListView is not retrieved.

Comment: Yes this task is nested inside of an activity Joel
@RyanGray I did it like you suggested and it worked, I updated the code in my question, code in the emulator works just fine now, but still it can not run inside my android device. WHen I run it just show the ProgressDialog, probably its because of the contacts where I use about 500 instead of the emulator where I use only 3.
Can you suggest a way to make it run on the device faster?
Thank you for your replies.

Comment: @RyanGray He could always preface that method call with ActivityClassName.this in order to ensure the correct content view is calling the function.. the list will be retrieved then if it is in the current content view.

Comment: @mkounal Try putting a log statement in your while loop, so each time you get a new contact and store it.. you can watch what happens and see the current count.  See if the data is being retrieved or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. why is the adapter created twice (yet used only once) , and inside the runInBackground? should it be created only after the raw data was fetched , in the onPostExecute?
2. is it possible that you didn't implement the adapter nicely ? have you watched the "the world of listView" video of google? please show the adapter's code.
3. what is the exception of the crash?

Comment: You are correct for 1.I will run the code at Monday and check the results and info you.
For 3. I dont see any exception when I run the app on the mobile device, I just see the Dialog run for a huge amount of time.
Is there any chance I use the AsyncTask somewhere wrong? I call it in the onStart method.

 Thank you

Comment: but you wrote that "the app crashes" . do you say that the app works fine , yet it's just slow?

Comment: Yes It is terribly slow, when I need 2 seconds for the emulator to retrieve the contacts, I need like 10 minutes for the device

Comment: hmmm ... how about an optimization trick? is it possible to store only the minimal data needed for the list of items , and load the extra ones by demand as they are shown by using the adapter? for example , load only the ids and names of the contacts , and then load (and store) their numbers when they are shown using getView . in any case , please try to measure the time it gets for each of the suspects of slowing down your app - getting the ids , getting the phone numbers , getting the names,... this way we could see what is the cause for the slowliness.

Comment: Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

Is it possible to do the query to a specific ID of the Cursor?

Comment: Ok could you suggest the way I should do the query?

Comment: well , you will need to explain more about what do you wish to do , and i will have to read more of how the content provider of the contacts works . i would recommend to inspect your priorities of what should be done . maybe do a lazy loading , or load all the extra information in the background, while giving more priority to things that the user should now see.

Comment: Well I found that I can use the cursor that way:

Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
      null , ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = " + mg, null, null);

in order to parse the database of the contacts for a specific ID without having to load the whole database.
But when I do 

id = ur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
the app crashes

any suggestions? :-)

Comment: inspect what you get in the cursor , by checking all of its columns . you might also want to specify exactly which columns you wish to get . read the API for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html